# how to output single alternates with bash nested for loop?

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, unix

I have a directory organized as follow:

```
1.0ps_DCA_md_center.xtc
1.0ps_DCA_npt.gro
1.2ps_DCA_md_center.xtc
1.2ps_DCA_npt.gro
1.8ps_DCA_md_center.xtc
1.8ps_DCA_npt.gro
2.0ps_DCA_md_center.xtc
2.0ps_DCA_npt.gro
```

and I would like to output with bash:

```
1.0ps_DCA_npt.gro
1.0ps_DCA_md_center.xtc
1.2ps_DCA_npt.gro
1.2ps_DCA_md_center.xtc
1.8ps_DCA_npt.gro
1.8ps_DCA_md_center.xtc
2.0ps_DCA_npt.gro
2.0ps_DCA_md_center.xtc
```

Notice the switch between `.gro` and `.xtc` files.

So far I have tried several combinations of for loops but nothing works.
I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

```
for i in *.gro; do echo $i; for j in *.xtc; do echo $j; done; done
```

```
1.0ps_DCA_npt.gro
1.0ps_DCA_md_center.xtc
1.2ps_DCA_md_center.xtc
1.8ps_DCA_md_center.xtc
2.0ps_DCA_md_center.xtc
1.2ps_DCA_npt.gro
1.0ps_DCA_md_center.xtc
1.2ps_DCA_md_center.xtc
1.8ps_DCA_md_center.xtc
2.0ps_DCA_md_center.xtc
1.8ps_DCA_npt.gro
1.0ps_DCA_md_center.xtc
1.2ps_DCA_md_center.xtc
1.8ps_DCA_md_center.xtc
2.0ps_DCA_md_center.xtc
2.0ps_DCA_npt.gro
1.0ps_DCA_md_center.xtc
1.2ps_DCA_md_center.xtc
1.8ps_DCA_md_center.xtc
2.0ps_DCA_md_center.xtc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this loop:

```
for i in *.gro; do
   echo "$i"
   echo "${i%_*}"*.xtc
done
```

```
1.0ps_DCA_npt.gro
1.0ps_DCA_md_center.xtc
1.2ps_DCA_npt.gro
1.2ps_DCA_md_center.xtc
1.8ps_DCA_npt.gro
1.8ps_DCA_md_center.xtc
2.0ps_DCA_npt.gro
2.0ps_DCA_md_center.xtc
```

`"${i%_*}"` will strip off right hand side of string starting with `_`